# Terraform - How to increment a variable under for_each loop?

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-aws, okta

I have a requirement to increment the priority in the below resource block for each of the data items present. eg: priority =1, priority =2 and so on.

```
resource "okta_app_group_assignments" "idc_app_assignments" {
    app_id   = okta_app_saml.aws_identity_center.id
    for_each = data.okta_groups.all_groups
    group {
       id       = each.value.groups.0.id
       priority = 1
    }
}
```

I could not use index function because data.okta_groups.all_groups is an object and it is not supported. Also, tried using a local variable and use that under priority, but it does not seem to work. Please let me know, if there is any way to achieve it.

```
    data "okta_groups" "all_groups" {
       for_each = {
          for okta_account in local.aws_okta_accounts : 
 "${okta_account.name}.${okta_account.role}.${okta_account.env_name}" => okta_account}
         q = "${each.value.name}-${each.value.env_name}#AWS#OKTA#${each.value.role}#${each.value.account_id}"
#example value for q - abc-dev#AWS#OKTA#dev#12345
}

example for data.okta_groups.all_groups: 
+ "abc.dev.qa"                           = {
      + groups = [
          + {
              + custom_profile_attributes = jsonencode({})
              + description               = ""
              + id                        = "00xxxxxxxxxxxxxb416"
              + name                      = "abc-qa#AWS#OKTA#dev#12345"
              + type                      = "OKTA_GROUP"
            },
        ]
      + id     = "987654"
      + q      = "abc-qa#AWS#OKTA#dev#12345"
      + search = null
      + type   = null
    }
```

Comment: Can you add the data source to the question? Also, would you mind adding an example output of that data source as well?

Comment: I have updated it, please check.

Comment: Not saying this will work, but you could explore something along the lines of `priority = length(each.value.groups) + 1`.

Comment: That sets priority = 2, for each group. I would want to increment it instead. Is there any way to use a local variable and perform increment operation there and use the value in resource block?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A Terraform map is not an ordered data structure, so there isn't any meaningful answer for "the index of a map element".

For collections that have a meaningful order, a list is the more appropriate data structure because it preserves the order in which the elements are defined. Therefore I would suggest changing your approach to use a list instead of a map.

I can't show a full example that works with your existing configuration because you've only included a small snippet of what you have, but here's a more contrived example showing the principle which hopefully you can adapt to suit your requirements:

```
variable "groups" {
  type = list(object({
    id = string
    # (and any other attributes you need)
  }))
}

resource "okta_app_group_assignments" "idc_app_assignments" {
  app_id   = okta_app_saml.aws_identity_center.id

  dynamic "group" {
    for_each = var.groups
    content {
      id       = group.value.id
      priority = group.key + 1
    }
  }
}
```

It seems like your situation needs a single resource with multiple `group` blocks rather than a separate resource for each group, so here I've used a [`dynamic` block](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/expressions/dynamic-blocks) to achieve that.

`dynamic` blocks allow collections of any type in their `for_each` because, unlike with `resource`-level `for_each`, Terraform does not need to individually track each block For nested blocks, that's the provider's responsibility, and providers can decide whether to treat a sequences of blocks as an ordered list or as some other kind of data structure.

Inside the `content` block of `dynamic "group"`, `group.key` represents the key of the current element, and since `var.groups` is a list the "keys" in this case are the list element indices. `group.key` will therefore be integers counting up from zero, and so I added one to instead produce integers counting up from one.

`group.value` is the current element *value*, similar to `each.value` for resource-level `for_each`, and so `group.value.id` is the `id` attribute from the current element.

---

If you *did* need to do this with `resource`-level `for_each` instead of a `dynamic` block then that's possible too, but it requires an extra step: Terraform cannot use a list for resource-level `for_each` because that doesn't give Terraform enough information to decide a tracking key for each instance of the resource.

In that case then, the typical answer is to use a [`for` expression](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/expressions/for) to project the list into a map just before assigning it to `for_each`, like this:

```
resource "example" "example" {
  for_each = tomap({
    for idx, group in var.groups : group.id => merge(
      group,
      { priority = idx + 1 },
    )
  })

  # ...
}
```

This `for` expression produces a map that has one element for each element of the given list, and switches it to identify each element by its `id` attribute instead of by its index.

But the index is still needed to decide the priority, so the `merge` call adds an extra `priority` attribute to each object which would then be available as `each.value.priority` for other arguments in the `resource` block.

Comment: Thank you so much for the detailed explanation. I got a better understanding of the task.  With slight adjustments I made it work using 2nd approach. Really appreciate your help.